# Como hago para activar un boton que esta desactivado en un pagina web con selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Mi problema es que hay un boton para registrar(Sign Up), que hasta que le des a una opcion en este caso recaptcha, esta desactivado. He visto que si voy al elemento y quito manualmente el **disabled:""** en el codigo html ,logro poder activarlo, pero necesito hacerlo automatizado con selenium.

Estoy usando el api de 2cpatcha y hace todo como asignarme el codigo o token e ingresarlo al recuadro para el submit pero en este caso el boton de registrar permanece desactivado hasta que no active manualmente el reCAPTCHA.

Me vendria bien alguna ayuda. Gracias. La pagina donde estoy tratando de registrar es https://stocktwits.com/

Comment: Hola Amigo lograste hacerlo? Tengo la misma duda

Comment: Saludos...no logre hacerlo en el momento pero como pase a otro projecto, no segui insistiendo. Disculpa. Pero alguien respondio sobre usar execute_script para modificar el HTML

Answer (score 1):

Amigo recientemente tuve el mismo incoveniente por lo que investigando y realizando pruebas esto me dio resultado con el siguiente código:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('#').removeAttribute('disabled');)
```

Aquí se identifica al botón y se elimina su atributo disabled de esta forma ya se tiene habilitado al botón.

Answer (score 0):

Cómo lo sugieren las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922259/modify-innerhtml-using-selenium) de SO, Selenium no brinda medios directos para modificar el código HTML.

Lo que si puedes, es cargar código Javascript que haga lo que necesites. Un ejemplo cambiando el fondo del body:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.background = 'orange'")
```

Indaga más sobre `execute_script` [aquí](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) o vista la [documentación oficial](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/).